# Symfony 2 form : entity widget with many to one/one to many relation - relation not persisting

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have a Audit form, to which i can attach several ressources ***(Audit has many Ressources, a ressource is attached to only one audit***).

the form is well presented in the view, yet, when saving the form, the selected ressources are not attached to the audit in the DB.

Audit Form :

```
>add('ressources', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'SpriMonitorBusinessBundle:Ressource',
            'query_builder' => $this->em->getRepository('SpriMonitorBusinessBundle:Ressource')->getAvailableRessources(true),
            'multiple'=>true
    ))
```

Audit.orm.yml:

```
oneToMany:
    ressources:
      targetEntity: Ressource
      mappedBy: audit
```

Ressource.orm.yml:

```
manyToOne:
    audit:
      targetEntity: Audit
      inversedBy: ressources
      joinColumn:
        name: audit_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

***N.B: On the Ressource form, when i select an audit, it is correctly saved***

Controller:

```
public function newAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $item = AuditFactory::make();
        $form = $this->createForm(new AuditType($em),$item);

        $request = $this->get('request');
        $session = $this->get('session');

        if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) {
            try {

                $this->validateForm($form,$request);
                $em->persist($item);
                $em->flush();
                $message  = $this->container->getParameter('form_submit_success');
                $session->setFlash('success', $message);
                $url = $this->generateUrl('Spri_audit_list');

                return $this->redirect($url);

            } catch (FormException $e) {
                $session->setFlash('error', sprintf('Erreur Formulaire : "%s"',$e->getMessage()));
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                die(var_dump($e->getMessage()));
                $session->setFlash('error', sprintf('Erreur inconnue !  Contactez l\'ADMIN'.$e->getMessage()));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('SpriAuditBundle:Audit:new.html.twig', array('form'=>$form->createView()));
    }

    protected function validateForm($form, $request)
    {
        $form->bind($request);
        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            $message  = $this->container->getParameter('form_submit_error');
            throw new FormException($message);
        }
    }
```

var_dump($item) shows:

```
private 'slug' => null
  private 'ressources' => 
    object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[4190]
      private '_elements' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(Spri\MonitorBusinessBundle\Entity\Ressource)[3766]
              ...
  privat...
```

Any idea??

Comment: Can you post your controller where you persist and flush the Entity Manager?

Comment: If you do a var_dump($item) just before the persist, does it show the Resources as children?

Comment: we need to see your create action as well.

Comment: @Lighthart : what create action ?

Comment: The symfony pattern is normally newAction returns a render of the newPage, which generates a form that posts to a createAction.  You are posting directly (bypassing createAction idea) but returning a new form.  You should be returning a showAction.  Also, is your AuditType (formType) configured properly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `Audit` entity in the `Ressource` entities manually by editing the `addRessource()` method of the entity.

Just edit this method like:

```
public function addRessource(Ressource $ressource)
{
    $this->ressources[] = $ressource;
    $ressource->setAudit($this);

    return $this;
}
```

**UPD**

Then try to persist ressources manually in the controller:

```
foreach ($audit->getRessources() as $ressource) {
    $em->persist($ressource);
}
```

**UPD**

Well, strange. Execute the next code snippet and check ressources relation:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$ressource = new Ressource();
$ressource->setSomeRequiredFieldValue($someValue);

$audit = new Audit();
$audit->setSomeRequiredFieldValue($someValue);
$audit->addRessource($ressource);

$em->persist($audit);
$em->persist($ressource);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Have you added "cascade: [persist]" (not sure about syntax, i never use schema files) to the resources property of Audit entity in the schema?

Comment: yes :oneToMany:
    ressources:
      targetEntity: Ressource
      mappedBy: audit
      cascade: ["persist", "merge"]

Comment: I have updated my answer. I'm sure cascade persist and first step in my answer should work. Also try to update Symfony to the recent version.

Comment: I did what you asked but nothing changed!

Comment: I have a Symfony version 2.2.0

Comment: the code result is correct, the result is correct. i have the ressource audit_id filled with the audit's one :) STRANGE

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I figured out what's going on.  This updated controller should fix your issue:

```
public function newAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $item = AuditFactory::make();
    $form = $this->createForm(new AuditType($em),$item);

    $request = $this->get('request');
    $session = $this->get('session');

    if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) {
        try {

            $this->validateForm($form,$request);

            $newItem = $form->getData();

            $em->persist($newItem);
            $em->flush();
            $message  = $this->container->getParameter('form_submit_success');
            $session->setFlash('success', $message);
            $url = $this->generateUrl('Spri_audit_list');

            return $this->redirect($url);

        } catch (FormException $e) {
            $session->setFlash('error', sprintf('Erreur Formulaire : "%s"',$e->getMessage()));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            die(var_dump($e->getMessage()));
            $session->setFlash('error', sprintf('Erreur inconnue !  Contactez l\'ADMIN'.$e->getMessage()));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('SpriAuditBundle:Audit:new.html.twig', array('form'=>$form->createView()));
}
```

Comment: Am still having the same result.

Comment: Last thing I can think of is to try and add a cascade persist to the Ressource entity.

Comment: I don't see what you'r thinking of  !?

Comment: The Resources that are being added, are they being inserted as new Resource entities or are they already managed entities in the database?

Comment: they already exist on the DB, i only choose them in the audit form

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to duplicate the behavior.  If its not a prod site maybe drop and rebuild the schema?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26570/discussion-between-ken-hannel-and-meznati)

Comment: You don't need to retrieve entity from the form. Objects are passed by references.

Comment: @VadimAshikhman : Actually i need to specify some options to the query retreiving the objects. Is there any other possibility ?